# Why \include doesn't include a file with space in the path name?

Tags: include, paths, folders

What is wrong with `\include{"./folder/another\space folder/lastfolder/file"}` that the file is not included while \input would include it?

Comment: I doubt that you really want to know the ugly details ;-) If you have a current tex system you can try with the newest latex-dev format.  Simply compile with `pdflatex-dev` instead of `pdflatex`. The quotes should then not be necessary.

Comment: I ancient times, when people threw stones at the dinosaur (https://polandin.com/41105514/expms-dinosaur-size-gaffe), names of files have up to 8 characters and the spaces in them were unneeded, so the usage of such names was not implemented in TeX. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- pre-dinosaurs, the limit (as on the SAIL computer where TeX was created), the limit was 6+3.

Answer (score 1):

TeX (original TeX) will not accept a space in a file name. Later TeX-like engines do, if the name is in quotes. When LaTeX was recently modified to accept spaces in file names for `\input`, the code for `\include` was not similarly updated. I don't know why, so this shouldn't be an "answer", but I can say there is no reason it could not have been updated to allow spaces.

Comment: the code for include was updated now (it was a bit more complicated as the code for \includeonly had to be adapted too).